# Google API php quickstart listFiles() 500 Internal Error

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I tried the [Example CLI PHP code](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/php) from Google.  The `listFiles()` method throws a 500 Internal Error from Google's servers, as shown in the stack trace:

> bash-4.2$ php test.php
>       PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?maxResults=10: (500) Internal Error' in /home/ben/.../vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php:79
>       Stack trace:
>       #0 /home/ben/.../vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php(44): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_Http_Request))
>       #1 /home/ben/.../vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php(556): Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(Google_Client), Object(Google_Http_Request))
>       #2 /home/ben/.../vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Service/Resource.php(195): Google_Client->execute(Object(Google_Http_Request))
>       #3 /home/ben/.../vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Service/Drive.php(1783): Google_Service_Resource->call('list', Array, 'Google_Service_...')
>       #4 /home/ben/.../test.php(78): Google_Service_Drive_Files_Resource->listFiles(Arra in /home/ben/.../vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 79

I deleted the saved credentials and tried again.  That did not help:

> bash-4.2$ php test.php
>       Open the following link in your browser:
>       https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=urn%3A
>       ietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&client_id=...&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.metadata.readonly&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=auto
>       Enter verification code: ...
>       Credentials saved to /home/ben/.credentials/drive-php-quickstart.json
>       PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?maxResults=10: (500) Internal Error' in /home/ben/.../vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php:79
>       Stack trace:
>       #0 /home/ben/.../vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php(44): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_Http_Request))
>       #1 /home/ben/.../vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php(556): Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(Google_Client), Object(Google_Http_Request))
>       #2 /home/ben/.../vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Service/Resource.php(195): Google_Client->execute(Object(Google_Http_Request))
>       #3 /home/ben/.../vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Service/Drive.php(1783): Google_Service_Resource->call('list', Array, 'Google_Service_...')
>       #4 /home/ben/.../test.php(78): Google_Service_Drive_Files_Resource->listFiles(Arra in /home/ben/.../vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 79

I searched through the github issues and stackoverflow questions tagged google-api-php-client, but did not find any clues.  I logged into the developer console and clicked Logs, which resulted in the text

> Failed to load.

Any ideas how to get more detailed information about 500 errors from Google?

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to the beginning of the code in the file calling Google Drive API
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York') //change timezone you want

Also make sure, folder permission inside the google drive is set.